# Help translating 安排当无品牌申报出到英国

Tags: translation

Can you help me out with the translation of the following sentence?

> 少量的商品代理应该可以安排当无品牌申报出到英国

“Representative with a small amount of goods should be able to arrange customs declaration of the trademark in England.”
Thank you in advance.

Comment: somewhat cryptic, perhaps: an agent for a small number of commodities should be able to declare these as non brandname items sent to Britain

Comment: Thank you very much! Everyday I face these type of sentences during my correspondence with my colleagues from Wenzhou and each time they write this way: non-standard, sometimes broken phrases and it makes me make my own mistakes while responding to them.

Comment: 安排当（成）无品牌（商品）申报（海关），出（口）到英国。I think this is what he/she wanted to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean:

代理应该可以把少量商品当成无品牌商品申报，出口到英国。

The agent can declear a small part of the goods as no-brand merchandise and export them to England.